# How to set a document for use with the Bera fonts instead the default fonts?

Tags: fonts, preamble

I have a document created with `scrartcl` class and I want to use the three Bera fonts: Serif, Sans and Mono, but I don't find the right way to change it with the KOMA-Script commands. Could someone tell me how do it?

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute,mexico]{babel}
%\usepackage[defaultsans]{berasans}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,empheq,bm}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}

\usepackage{url}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a Minimal Working Example providing at least the basics and, preferably, what you have tried. This is much more likely to get you help than asking would-be helpers to start from scratch with `\documentclass...`.

Comment: Loading the package `bera` the common way … Where’s your problem? (In other words I second cfr’s comment.)

Comment: The rpoblem is that I don't lnow how to set the document for use that typeface.

Comment: The optional argument `defaultsans` you give for the commented package `berasans` is not defined for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three packages `beramono`, `beraserif` and `berasans` and a wrapper package `bera`, which loads all of them at once:

```
\usepackage{bera}
```

What I suspect from your example code is, that you want to set the sans serif font as the default. This can be achieved if you add the following line after the above package loading:

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

Note, that this package/these packages has/have no math support. You must care separately.

---

Let me at the end point you to the package `dejavu` (also a wrapper package); a cite from the package introduction:

> This package contains the LaTeX support for the DejaVu fonts. These fonts 
>   are derived from the Vera fonts and there are already other Vera derivatives
>   on CTAN (Bera and Arev). The main reason why I created support for the
>   DejaVu fonts is that I am not satisfied with the Bera and Arev fonts for the
>   Czech and Slovak languages. However, other people should also benefit
>   from this package—the fonts support more languages and they have several
>   additional styles.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helping and suggestions, in fact I do not want to change the serif font for a sans serif, I want to use both in my document. About the maths, I think there is not a problem even if I can use correctly the `siunitx` package with these typefaces.