# Where do I put option values for customizing documents with KOMA Script classes?

Tags: koma-script, class-options

I started to read the documentation on the KOMA Script classes because they seem to have many tools that are more flexible to use than the standard classes, But I don't understand where to put all the options. Is within \documentclass the best place, or not?

By example:

```
\documentclass[headsepline=true,paper=letter,headings=small,DIV=10]{scrbook}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage[berasans]{quotchap}
\usepackage[nouppercase]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

This compiles well but the headsepline doesn't appear, and also the heading size doesn't change. If the class options are not the best place for it, where or how can I add these optional values?

On the other hand, regarding fonts, KOMA Script uses a sans serif for headings and other stuff, and serif fonts for text. After reading this: [How to set a document for use with the Bera fonts instead the default fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166785/how-to-set-a-document-for-use-with-the-bera-fonts-instead-the-default-fonts) 
I understand that if I want to use LaTeX fonts (without XeTeX) I need to load the page of each font and then KOMA will use them.  Am I right? [In the example I use bera fonts because the package include both fonts.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set KOMAoptions at nearly every point in the document,
but you have to make sure that they are passed and processed
correctly. With the (soon obsolete) package scrpage2 you had to
give the option headsepline to the package directly. Using the
new scrlayer-scrpage allows you to set the headsepline as a
documentclass option.
As [esdd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/43317/esdd) made me aware, that is not
correct. Package `scrpage2` simply doesn't know the
key-value-pair `headsepline=true`. One can set the global option
`headsepline` which will be picked up (even without loading a
special package) by setting `\pagestyle{headings}`. Setting
`\pagestyle{scrheadings}` (provided by `scrpage2`) also does the
trick.
With the successor `scrlayer-scrpage` the difference between
`headings` and `scrheadings` is gone.

```
\documentclass[headsepline=true,paper=letter,headings=small,DIV=10]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bera}
%\usepackage[berasans]{quotchap}
\usepackage[markcase=ignoreuppercase]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\clearpage
\KOMAoption{headsepline}{false}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Now to the fonts you mentioned. KOMA uses *a lot* of internal helper macros. That is the only way to provide a user with options like `headings=small`. The internal interface is, let's call it advanced. Packages like `quotchap` or `titlesec` use the basic LaTeX interface.

In comparison, KOMA provides a simple *user interface* working with a complicated *internal interface*. Getting a KOMA mechanic an tell him what to do, he opens his fancy-a** toolbox and gets to work. Now you call in the (standard) guy for the headings, he is not as advanced, but been around for a while. He's got one screwdriver and a hammer, that's it. And if something won't fit, a good whack with his hammer can solve the problem.

To sum it up, a package like `quotchap` messes up the well constructed internals of KOMA-script.

I just had a look at the documentation and code of package `quotchap`. It claims to cooperate with KOMA-script. It takes the definition of the original KOMA chapter and redefines it. `quotchap` started in 1998, 15 years have passed, lots of water went down stream and KOMA got *heavily* extended (adding specialized tools to the box). `quotchap` never learned these enhancements.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, how do you know the scrpage2 package will be obsolete, what should I learn instead? What do you recommend me to change the heading layout of the chapters without use quotchapt?

Comment: The german documentation is a bit more verbose on the matter of `scrpage2`. It states, that `scrlayer-scrpage` is more advanced and will be developed further. The development of `scrpage2` has stopped. Both packages have the same basic user interface.

Comment: Concerning the heading layout: It is basically the same as `quotchap` does it internally. Take the original definition and customize it to your needs. There are two ways, doing it simple but loosing optional features (`headings=small` etc) or doing a more robust approach, taking all the optional stuff into account. The decision is yours to take.

Comment: I tought about defining an interface taking into account the different keys for `headings` but i realized after a short time that this a pretty big amount of work, taking everything into account.

Comment: Thanks I understand and I think the same, I'll see how to do it easy.

Comment: http://www.komascript.de/comment/4874#comment-4874